# Number of binary substrings with minimum 3 consecutive identical characters

Tags: algorithm

I am learning algorithms and I am trying to solve problem with binary substrings.

I can think of only brute-force strategy. Is it possible to do it in a better way?

I will show my approach using example.

Consider the following binary string

```
010001
```

answer is 6 => (2,4), (1,4), (0,4), (2,5), (1,5), (0,5)

My approach:

1. Find substring with minimum 3 identical char.
2. Go into left and right and calculate result.
3. Repeat for every substring with min 3 identical char.

How can I do this better?

Comment: Yes, this is a combinatorial problem.

Comment: In the algorithm that you describe you must not forget to remove the duplicate substrings (simply stating you should also take care of double-counting)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah, but still I don't know how to bite it :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot do this in less than time `O(n)` because you have to scan the string to find all runs of 3 identical.

But to make it interesting, suppose that our string was `0100111000010`.  In a single scan we can make a list of all of the positions where we end a run of at least 3.  Counting the start of the string as `0`, those positions are `7, 10, 11` and the string has length 13.

Can we find the answer from that?

For the `5` starting positions from `0` to `7-3=4` and all `8` ending positions from and including `7` to `13` (be very careful of the potential fencepost errors!) we include the first run of 1s.  so there are `40` there.

For the `3` starting positions from `5` to `10-3=7` and all `4` ending positions from `10` to `13` we include the first `000` and that is `12` more.

For the `1` starting position from `8` to `11-3=8` and all `3` ending positions from `11` to `13` we include the second `000` and that is `3` more.

Therefore the answer is `40 + 12 + 3 = 55`.

Can you generalize this line reasoning and write a program?  If so, it will execute in time `O(n)` which is the best possible.